# Get a BsonDocument at a specific offset

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I need to get a document from a collection at a specific point - is there any way of doing this, or would I need to append a value into the document structure? More specifically, I need to get the document based on a random number... Something like this...

```
Random rand = new Random();
int randNumber = rand.Next(1, (int)bsonCollection.Count());

var document = bsonCollection.findDocumentAt(randNumber);
//     the function I'm after ^ or equivilient
```

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: I think this is a better solution (I didn't know about ElementAt, as I've never actually needed to do this):

```
var document = bsonCollection.FindAll().ElementAtOrDefault(randNumber);
```

You should be able to achieve this using skip on the cursor. Something like:

```
var cursor = bsonCollection.FindAll();
cursor.Skip = randNumber;
var document = cursor.FirstOrDefault();
```

Or slightly neater:

```
var document = bsonCollection.FindAll().SetSkip(randNumber).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: apparently there's no overload for `Find()` to take 0 arguments? So what would the query document be?

Comment: @JSmith It's `FindAll`

Comment: thanks @I3arnon, just went to edit and found you'd already fixed it.